# No restart button for running application in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I have run ,debug ,run with coverage and stop. But there is no button to restart my application.

intellij : 2020.1

Answer (score 1):

Run button changes to rerun if the app is still running. Screenshots from IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 in Debug and Run mode. You can see this button in Run and Debug tool windows as well as in the toolbar on the right of the run configuration name:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

You can also use the keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>).

If it doesn't work for you, please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).